# RxSwift: compactMap never executed

Tags: swift, rx-swift, behaviorrelay

I'm trying to implement `compactMap` on `RxSwift` but it seems like is never executed.

Here is my code:

```
class MyClass{

    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let subject = BehaviorRelay(value: 1)

    func doSomething() {
        Observable.from(optional: subject).compactMap{  $0

        }.subscribe( onNext:{
            print($0)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        subject.accept(2)
        subject.accept(4)
        subject.accept(5)
        subject.accept(8)
    }
}
```

When I change the value on `subject` the `compactMap` never gets called. Why not?

Comment: What do you mean by "never gets executed". What were you expecting to happen vs what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an `Observable<BehaviorRelay<Int>>` by using the `from` operator which only emits one value (the behavior relay itself) and then completes. The `accept` calls are being ignored because nothing is subscribing to the behavior relay itself.

I think you need to step back and figure out what you are trying to accomplish, and then read the documentation on the operators to find one that does what you need.

Comment: This does provide the answer, in the first part. I think you're being too bent on the comment where this does not actually make sense to notice that the first part says what's the actual behavior of the code posted.

Comment: I removed the critique of the code and expanded on the answer.